# I'm trying To Send Array with Serialize Form as a parameter from ajax to controller but the second parameter "test" giving null value

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

$("#CreateDepartmentForm").submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

```
        var modelx = $(this).serialize();
        console.log(modelx);
        var cars = [
            {
                "color": "purple",
                "type": "minivan",
                "registration": "2018-03-03",
                "capacity": 7
            },
            {
                "color": "red",
                "type": "station wagon",
                "registration": "2018-03-03",
                "capacity": 20
            }];
       
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Department/CreateDepartmentByAjax",
            data: modelx + "&test=" + cars,
            success: function (res) {
            },
         });
```

---

```
public IActionResult CreateDepartmentByAjax(DepartmentVM model,List<cars> test)
    {
     }
```

---

```
   public  class cars
{
    public string color  { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string registration { get; set; }
    public int capacity { get; set; }
}
```

---

[Ajax Code Image`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V61tf.png)

-----------

I'm trying To Send Array with Serialize Form as a parameter from ajax to controller  but the second parameter  "test" giving null value
So, the problem is that controller doesn't get the parameter test, I've tried many examples and tutorials but nothing helped. maybe there's some easy obvious mistake which I am missing? How could I pass parameters from ajax function to controller?

Comment: The data property in this case is the serialized version of your form data and is embedded in the HTTP request's body. You are trying to append the cars array in a fashion as if it were an URI parameter which is not going to work. I think instead you should serialize the cars array and include it in the body (data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the object to API by serializing the object as JSON.

```js
$("#CreateDepartmentForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var modelx = {};
    $(this).children("input").each(function () {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var value = $(this).val();
        modelx[name] = value;
    });

    ...
      

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Department/CreateDepartmentByAjax",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ model: modelx, test: cars }),
        success: function (res) {
        },
    });
});
```

And modify the controller:

```cs
public class CreateDepartmentInput
{
    public DepartmentVM model { get; set; }
    public List<cars> test { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateDepartmentByAjax([FromBody]CreateDepartmentInput input)
{
    ...
}
```

> Request Payload

[image: Request Payload]

> Visual Studio Debugging Output

[image: Visual Studio Debugging Output]

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your effort could you explain how to pass each object of array with form as object in the same model @Yong

Comment: The concept is the same as `test` property. You need to pass the whole object like `{ /*  Other properties*/, test: [ { ... } , /* Other objects */] } `.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass an array like query parameter for POST request you need to add [FromQuery] attribute to list parameter in you controller method. Instead it's better to put json payload to request body.